# Spring mvc: Controller method is not invoked

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and I have a following method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/web", "/web/"})
public void redirectToIndexUi(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        //some condition
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/ui/index.html");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException is thrown while trying to redirect to index.html page.", ex);
    }
}
```

When a user enters the following url http://localhost:8080/myapp/web/  redirectToIndexUi method is called, but in this case http://localhost:8080/myapp/web/index.html the redirectToIndexUi  method is not called. What could be the reason ?

Comment: You really won't like that as it would result in an endless redirect loop!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your controller not invoked is your mapping. You are mapping your controller method to URI `'/web'` and not `'/web/index.html'`.

And you can use wildcard characters like `'/web/**'` to point every request with /web/ in it to use your controller's method. So that your method will be called whenever your request hits anything similar to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/web/**`.

Comment: If you want to get the redirect behaviour for all pages under /web/ you can use the mapping '/web/*'